# How to raise a message when two moving labels are touching each other

Tags: c#, winforms, label, point

label 1:

```
lblLeftToRight.Location = new Point(lblLeftToRight.Location.X + 10, lblLeftToRight.Location.Y);
```

label 2:

```
lblLeftToRight.Location = new Point(lblLeftToRight.Location.X - 10, lblLeftToRight.Location.Y);
```

By Using `timer` and `Point` structure, I am moving label1 and label2.
I want to raise a message when both labels contact each other.

Comment: What do you mean by "moving labels"? How are they being moved. You probably want to do some calculation based on .Location and .Size whenever they get moved.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You'll need to include a bit more in your question, i.e. a question, rather than just a couple of lines of code.  Please outline what you want to do, what you've tried, and what didn't work when you tried it

Comment: I think you are trying to say that whenever you drag a label with mouse, the label should be draggable and when it reaches the vicinity of the other label you want to avoid contact with it ?

Comment: I'm sorry, you need to explain the problem more clearly.  Labels don't move - you'll have to have written something to move them.  So, you get to decide how to raise the message.  What approach have you tried?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple enough : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0.aspx

Labels have: top, left, height and width

```
Rectangle r1 = new rectangle (label1.left,label1.top,label1.width,label1.height);
Rectangle r2 = new rectangle (label2.left,label2.top,label2.width,label2.height);

if  (r1.IntersectsWith(r2))
{
// do stuff
}
```